# Decoding manchester mit custom preamble in PIO

Tags: rp2040

I'm trying to decode a MVB train protocol using RP2040. The protocol is using special preamble for master and slave frames. Frame looks like:

*11111 01100011100010101   01 10 01 01 01 01 01 01    01 10 01 10 01 01 01 01     01 01 10 01 01 01 10 10   0011111*

Where *01100011100010101* is the master preamble. *101010100011100011* Any ideas how to detect the master/slave preamble with PIO? It could start Manchester decoding in another state machine with IRQ.